# Runtime error 5, invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, excel

By the odd chance, can anyone see what is wrong with the VB codes below.

> Runtime error 5, invalid procedure call or argument

The Error is highlighted on the below chunk of code

```
wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=AND(COUNTIF(Ratecard!Q:Q,BC3)=0,AN3>0) = TRUE"
```

Here is the whole code:

```
    Sub TestLook()
Set wsWhiteCollar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("White Collar")
Set wssheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WEW")

wsWhiteCollar.Activate

'wssheet1.Activate

EndWC = wssheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'i.e. column B last row 24 to 25 on my WEW table


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each c In wsWhiteCollar.Range(wsWhiteCollar.Range("A2"), wsWhiteCollar.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For x = 2 To EndWC Step 1
        wssheet1.Activate
        wssheet1.Range("B" & x).Select

        If c.Value = wssheet1.Range("B" & x).Value Then

            wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions.Delete
            wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=AND(COUNTIF(Ratecard!Q:Q,BC3)=0,AN3>0) = TRUE"
            wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions(1).SetFirstPriority

            With wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

            wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
                "=AND(COUNTIFS(White Collar!A:A,B3, White Collar!U:U,BC3)=0, AV3=0) = TRUE"

            With wssheet1.Range("BC" & x).FormatConditions(2).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 49407
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Exit For
        ElseIf Selection.Interior.ThemeColor <> xlThemeColorAccent2 Then
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
        wsWhiteCollar.Activate
    Next x
Next c
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'wssheet1.Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot reference other sheets in a conditional formatting formula, you will find removing `Ratecard!` should remove the error, but then not give you the formula you desire.

Comment: Just be aware you have the same issue further down with `White Collar!`, so will need to sort a work around for that too.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your feedback so promptly.  I had a similar formula of using the Ratecard! within the conditional formula which works fine but strangely can't seems to figure the issue with my latest post.  Any other things that strikes out as "wrong" on my code on that issue that you can spot?

Comment: Are you **certain** the sheet name is correct? Also, do you really mean to refer to row 3 in the formatting for every cell?

Comment: Hi Rory, many thanks for your feedback.  I have checked and the sheet names are correct for each one. The code is looking up row 3 as first row is the title, second row is the column header hence third row is the first cell value for WEW worksheet/tbl.  As for worksheet White Collar, the start cell for comparison is the range A2 onwards to the end row.  There are other columns for comparison as well for these 3 worksheets/table.   Apologies for the lengthy explanation.  Any other things that sticks out that are potentially "wrong" on my code?

Answer (score 0):

Place the formula COUNTIF(Ratecard!Q:Q,BC3) in a new cell and then reference that cell in your Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your suggestions.  Would you be able to share an example as not too sure how to do this?